# Outer product of each column of a 2D array to form a 3D array - NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Let X be a M x N matrix. Denote xi the i-th column of X. I want to create a 3 dimensional N x M x M array consisting of M x M matrices `xi.dot(xi.T)`.

How can I do it most elegantly with numpy? Is it possible to do this using only matrix operations, without loops?

Comment: Sounds like a job for np.einsum.

Comment: It seems as if the (rows,cols) have been mixed up here...To use concrete numbers, assume we begin with (Mrows, Ncols) = (2,3). The OP is using column vector operations `Ni*Ni.T`. Each column is of length Mrows=2, so the product yields a (2,2) matrix - that is, (Mrows,Mrows). Doing that for each column and stacking the result in the third dimension should result in an (M x M x N) matrix.

Comment: @MattP OP is probably stacking/storing along the first axis : `for i in range(N):  out[i] =  X[:,i,None].dot(X[None,:,i])`.

Comment: @Divakar That's some pretty nice broadcasting/indexing there! I learned something new here today. My own (less fancy, more loopy, and likely less performant) solution to this question that gives the same result would have been: `Result = np.dstack( X[:,i].reshape((nrows,1)) * X[:,i] for i in range(ncols) )`.

Comment: @MattP An *easier* version would be : `xi = X[:,i,None]` and then using OP's code : `xi.dot(xi.T)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One approach with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
X.T[:,:,None]*X.T[:,None]
```

Another with `broadcasting` and swapping axes afterwards -

```
(X[:,None,:]*X).swapaxes(0,2)
```

Another with `broadcasting` and a multi-dimensional transpose afterwards -

```
(X[:,None,:]*X).T
```

Another approach with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which might be more intuitive thinking in terms of the iterators involved if you are translating from a loopy code -

```
np.einsum('ij,kj->jik',X,X)
```

Basic idea in all of these approaches is that we *spread out* the last axis for elementwise multiplication against each other keeping the first axis aligned. We achieve this process of putting *against each other* by extending `X` to two `3D` array versions.